# Unity Collaborate vs GitHub

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, version

I am working in a small team of three on a Unity game project. What are the pros and cons of using Unity Collaborate as opposed to GitHub on Unity?

Based on my understanding, both act as version control and allow cloud hosting for team members to stay in sync. Unity Collaborate does not seem to have a branching feature so it may be more difficult to ensure that all codes merged are working codes; is this the only disadvantage of Unity Collaborate?

Comment: If you choose git, just remember to use [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/) for binaries or big files

Answer (score 8):

Unity Collaborate is useful for merging scenes and has little to no learning curve. However, when I tried to use it a few months ago I found that its features are severely limited. It's built to be as simple as possible to use however this is also its main flaw, as there are no settings or configurations. I only used it for a few days before I ran into a conflict error that I was unable to resolve. I highly recommend just sticking to git, it's much more reliable and fit for purpose. If Unity wants to compete they need to do a much better job. Personally I use BitBucket and SourceTree for the free private repository and friendly UI.

Comment: github also provides free private repositories now and SourceTree provides support for github as well

Answer (score 4):

I've used both Unity Collaborate and GitHub.

**Unity Collaborate:** When I used Unity's source control I found it was missing a lot of features, it doesn't have branches so everyone is stuck working on the same 'branch'. I found detecting and merging conflicts was not very good, I got some false conflicts and when trying to merge it just would overwrite an entire file instead of allowing the user to choose which parts of the code to overwrite. I didn't find any of Unity's other services that are included with collaborate to be any use either. It also costs money to upload the project to the cloud and buy 'seats' to allow other contributors to join the project. You can not open you're project to the public or make it open source (this might not be a problem for you and your projects). However, there is no learning curve, its simple to use and is all inside Unity from the very beginning of the project.

**GitHub:** I personally use [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) to pull and push to GitHub rather than the [plugin](https://unity.github.com/) GitHub released a few years ago. GitHub is a little more difficult to use and will require you to learn how it works and possibly download other programs in order for it to work. But, it has a load more features than Unity Collab, it has branches, a built in issues tracker, you can link it to a [trello](https://trello.com) or [glo](https://www.gitkraken.com/boards) board. It has a free option with infinite private and public repositories, with infinite contributors. It also has a built-in [wiki page](https://guides.github.com/features/wikis/) and you can create and host a [website](https://pages.github.com/) for your project, all inside the same repository. However, GitHub can not track large files very easily, so if your project contains a lot of big models then you might have to use [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/). Unfortunately, large files are not free to host on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

Github is trying to convince you that it is a good choice. They just announced the v1 of Github for Unity:

https://blog.github.com/2018-06-18-announcing-github-for-unity-1.0/

Answer (score 2):

My team uses Unity Collaborate an we have the most time no problems, it is more easier to work parallel on the project without deleting each others work. I recomend it to you and the 9bucks are it worth.

Comment: Please don't add *"Me too"* as an answer. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you're interested in this specific question, you can show your interest by [upvoting](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it or leaving a [comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) once you have enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: I don´t wrote it but ok, I wrote only about my experience.... so it was a valid answer, wasn´t it?

Comment: @Kristian Thanks for telling by your experience, it helped me.